# get Values from uiwebview's webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i am working with java script in objective - C.

Following is my code :

```
NSString *javascript = @"testfunction = function(){ jQuery.getScript(\"https://www.myserver.com/myscript.js\").done(function(script,textStatus){$testvalue = 10; return $testvalue; }).fail(function(jqXHR,settings,exception){\n alert(exception);});}";

[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];

NSString *value = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"testfunction();"];
NSLog(@"Value of Value : %@",value);
```

now The Problem is:

i want value in my value variable how can i get it?

Answer (score 1):

download [code example](https://github.com/Yuyutsu/callJsWithObjectiveC)

**follow these step:**

create JS file **demo.js** and add code

```
var hello = function(str){
   return str;
};
```

add UIWebView => To embed JavaScript in a dummy html file and load that into the UIWebView

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:@"<script src=\"demo.js\"></script>"
              baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
```

Here is the code to make JS call

```
NString *str=@"hi JavaScript";
NSString *function = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"hello(%@)", str];
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:function];
```

Now, there is one important safety tip to make this actually work: The UIWebView must actually be loaded a view. It doesn’t have to be visible, but in order for the WebKit engine to execute the JS, it must be on a view.

This might helps you :)

Comment: thanks for quick reply i already did it. but i want the value into my objective c variable from javascript how can i ?

Answer (score 1):

add delegate to your webview

```
_webView.delegate =self;
```

use this code

```
NSString *fName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"demo()"];
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:fName];
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but it's basic think what i am doing but still i am not getting value of that variable into my objective c code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIWebView`'s delegate method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` to intercept URL requests. Make a fake request when you need to return some data from JS function, intercept it, handle, and return `NO`.

Read [here](http://blog.grio.com/2012/07/uiwebview-javascript-to-objective-c-communication.html) for details.